# Android app crashes when proguard enabled with release apk: NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/koin/core/context/GlobalContextKt;

Tags: android, koin

I am facing with problem (app crashes at start) with release apk, when enabling proguard.

Here is stack trace:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxx.yyyy, PID: 24018
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/koin/core/context/GlobalContextKt;
at com.xxxx.yyyy.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.kt:31)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1202)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:308)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2295)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.koin.core.context.GlobalContextKt
at com.xxxx.yyyy.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.kt:31) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1202) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:308) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2295) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)

Here is my Application class, where I start koin:

````
```    class MyApp : Application() {
    companion object {
        var language: String? = null
    }

    @ExperimentalContracts
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Start Koin
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@MyApp)
            androidLogger(Level.DEBUG)
            modules(
                listOf(
                    appModule,
                    networkModule,
                    activityModules
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        if (base != null) {
            super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base))
        }
        else {
            super.attachBaseContext(base)
        }
    }
} ```
````

Koin version: 2.0.1
What is interesting that only crashes in release signed apk when minifyEnabled = true. But if debug build with minifyEnabled = true, it does not crashes!
I am aware I didn't post more sample code but it is very difficult to investigate what causes crash from logs for release apk.
Already read some issue reports on GitHub, but no help for me. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You'll need proguard keep rules for the koin library which *should* already be provided by them so that when you include their library, these rules will automatically be picked up.  However, it looks like there is an [issue](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/552) with this.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but it still doesn't work. I have also upgraded Koin version from 2.0.1 to 2.1.16, the same crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem. I totally forgot that last week I changed in gradle import for firebase-crashlytics library(using new way). Also removed keep class crashlytics in proguard-roles file.

Comment: I have the same issue but how did the new firebase fixed the issue? I mean that i have the new crashlytics imported but no difference found. Problem still exists